# MySQL use of LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I have two recordset I'm using to select and display data.  The following query works great and shows me the first 25 records.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE Field3 = '".$currentag."' 
   AND Field1 = 'A' 
   AND Field1 != 'D' 
 LIMIT 25
```

How do I create a new, separate query to display records AFTER the initial 25 records are returned?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: But in case when `order by` is the same as `default` order (accordingly to primary key)  - it make sense to omit `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `offset`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE Field3 = '".$currentag."' AND Field1 = 'A' AND Field1 != 'D'
LIMIT 25, 25
```

One more batch:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE Field3 = '".$currentag."' AND Field1 = 'A' AND Field1 != 'D'
LIMIT 50, 25
```

Here 50 - is offset and 25 - is limit.

Comment: Likewise, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry Agree with you that with `order by` it make more sense.

Comment: Yep, also this approach is open to sql injection attack.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you mean `$currentag` variable?

Comment: @Strawberry In case var `$currentag` already validated and escaped - it's ok, in case not - yes it's vulnerable place.

Comment: No. It's vulnerable either way.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for LIMIT $point,$offset is that $point means starting point and $offset is number of entries you want to display so for your query solution is LIMIT 25,25 then dynamically you pass values as a variable from frontend to these 2variables.